# bing news search API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing, bing-api

How does the "freshness" parameter of the Bing news search API work?

I am writng a program to call the Bing news search API.
I set the "freshness" parameter to be "Month". Yet, Bing returned content that can be as old as 6 months ago. How did I find out? I use the offset parameter to retrieve the last new pages of the returned result and found out that they are can be as old as 6 months (some even 2 years odl). Clarly, this result is contradict to the fresness parameter that I put in. Can anyone shed some light on this?  Many thanks,

The following is the code snippet:
Basically, I set the freshness to be Month (freshness=Month) and sort the output by day (sortBy=Day).

```
   let bing_news_search = function (search) {
console.log('Searching news for: ' + term);
let request_params = {
    method: 'GET',
    hostname: host,
    path: path + '?q=' + encodeURIComponent('Microsoft') +'&count=100'+'&freshness=Month'+'&sortBY=Date'+'&offset=4979900',
    headers: {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
    }
```

Comment: I believe the Freshness=Month parameter is correct. Does the same type of behavior happen if you set freshness=day or freshness=week?

Comment: The same. Month, Week or Day doesn't make any differecne. As a matter of fact,  several of the first 100 returned articles were published last year when I set the freshness to be day or week (freshness=Week/Day), It is as if the input fresness parameter isn't doing anything at all.

Comment: What is the functionality and purpose of the freshness parameter -- A better way to phrase the question.

Comment: Following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-news-search/tutorial-bing-news-search-single-page-app

Maybe you could you try something like 'freshness=' + 'Month'

Comment: I tried 'freshness=' + 'Month' and no luck. The same result.

Comment: one article was from 2014, one from 2015 and another from 2016 (they are all within the first 100 articles returned by the API).  In fact, the response only stated that the output is sorted by day (sortby=Day) and didn't say anything about the freshness of the output.

Comment: What if you remove the time contrasts and just use the number of articles? Does it get the latest?

Comment: Even worse. One returned article was published in 1975.

Comment: here is the code, you can try it for yoruself.   let request_params = {
        method: 'GET',
        hostname: host,
        path: path + '?q=' + encodeURIComponent('Microsoft ') +'&count=100',
        headers: {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
        }

Comment: Can you share the documentation you were basing your code off of?

Comment: Sure, where can i send it to? It is too long to post it as comment. thanks

Comment: Is it not a link to an online doc somewhere?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-news-search/nodejs

Comment: @MIcah_MSFT, please let me know if you need  anything else. thx

Comment: Quick update, I am working with some internal teams to see if I can find an answer for you. Will update you once I have more information

Comment: So it appears one of the issues is that we have Count=100 and 50 is the limit. I set mine to 50 and it seems to be working well. Can you try?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Let ne give it a try !

Comment: Hi Mikey. Any update?

Comment: Yes, it works well if the count is lower to 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this to the Answer as verified in comments:

The issue is that the &count is set to 100. The current limit is 50. Once setting this number correctly the API will work as expected.

So it will look like so:

```
 let bing_news_search = function (search) {
console.log('Searching news for: ' + term);
let request_params = {
    method: 'GET',
    hostname: host,
    path: path + '?q=' + encodeURIComponent('Microsoft') +'&count=50'+'&freshness=Month'+'&sortBY=Date'+'&offset=4979900',
    headers: {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
```

Comment: I have a question on this, I am facing issues in the freshness parameter. In the documentation on the site [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-web-api-v7-reference), they have mentioned we can use a single date as well a range of date for the freshness parameter. I trying the same but it is not working for me. Following are my list of parameters:

params = {"q": search_term, "textDecorations": True, "textFormat": "HTML", "count": 50, "freshness": '2020-04-27'}

Where, I am getting error in the freshness parameter.